# Symmetric undirected $p$-median instance with fractional LP solution?

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, facility-location, p-median, lp-relaxation

The $p$-median problem is NP-hard, so its LP relaxation does not naturally have all-integer solutions. However, it very often does; in fact, it can be hard to find an instance for which the LP relaxation solution is *not* integer.

The only examples that I know of for which the LP solution is non-integer use *asymmetric* distances (or, equivalently, directed graphs)—for example, the examples by [ReVelle and Swain (1970)](https://doi.org/10.1111/j.1538-4632.1970.tb00142.x) and [Baïou and Barahona (2011)](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.disopt.2010.12.002).

**Is there a symmetric, undirected $p$-median instance for which the optimal solution to the LP relaxation is not integer?** I'm especially looking for small examples (say, 5 nodes).

Comment: Which formulation do you have in mind?

Comment: The standard one (at least I’d consider it standard). For example see (2.1)-(2.6) of [Daskin and Maass 2015](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/2094/882d425fe9b3f668eaafbcf8ac0bba478b5f.pdf).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think I've found an instance with four nodes and $p = 2$ via brute force (a lot of randomized instances). I've attached my Python script as well. I relaxed the [Daskin and Maass (2015)](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/2094/882d425fe9b3f668eaafbcf8ac0bba478b5f.pdf) formulation and assumed $I = J$.

Nodes: $I = J = \{1, 2, 3, 4\}$

Demands: $d = (75, 34, 40, 40)$

Costs (or distances):

$$
c = 
    \begin{bmatrix}
    0  & 39 & 95 & 7  \\
    39 & 0  & 83 & 18 \\
    95 & 83 & 0  & 16 \\
     7 & 18 & 16 & 0\\    
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

Gurobi gives the following solution:

$$ y = (0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5 )$$

$$
x = 
    \begin{bmatrix}
    0.5  & 0 & 0 & 0.5  \\
    0 & 0.5  & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0.5  & 0 \\
    0.5 & 0.5 & 0.5 & 0.5\\    
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

The optimal demand-weighted cost is $1028.5$.

---

Code:

```py
# Edited to add code highlighting
from gurobipy import *
import numpy as np
from random import *

## DEFINE MODEL ###

def p_median_relaxed(I, J, c, d, p):
    model = Model("relaxed")

    model.setParam('OutputFlag', 0) 

    ######### VARIABLES AND BOUNDS #########
    x = {} 
    y = {} # the (binary) facility location variable being relaxed

    for i in I:
        for j in J:
            x[i, j] = model.addVar(vtype = GRB.CONTINUOUS, lb = 0)

    for i in I:
        y[i] = model.addVar(vtype = GRB.CONTINUOUS, lb = 0, ub = 1)

    ######### CONSTRAINTS #########

    # (2.2)
    for j in J:
        model.addConstr(quicksum(x[i, j] for i in I) == 1, name = "c1_{}".format(j))

    # (2.3)
    model.addConstr(quicksum(y[i] for i in I) == p, name = "c2")

    # (2.4)
    for i in I:
        for j in J:
            model.addConstr(x[i, j] - y[i] <= 0, name = "c3_{}_{}".format(i, j))

    ######### OBJECTIVE ##########

    model.setObjective(quicksum((d[j] * c[i, j] * x[i, j]) for i in I for j in J), GRB.MINIMIZE)

    ############ SOLVE ###########

    model.optimize()

    ### STORE AND RETURN SOLUTION ###

    x_val = {}
    y_val = {}

    for i in I:
        y_val[i] = y[i].x

        for j in J:
            x_val[i, j] = x[i, j].x

    return(x_val, y_val, model.objVal)


## CREATE RANDOMIZED INSTANCES AND SOLVE ##

siz = 4 # size of network

I = range(1, 5)
J = range(1, 5)
c = {}
d = {}

found_flag = 0

for ii in range(1000):
    p = randrange(2, siz)

    for j in J:
        d[j] = randrange(0, 100, 1)

        for i in I:

            if i == j:
                c[i, j] = 0
            elif i < j:
                c[i, j] = randrange(0, 100, 1)

    for i in I:
        for j in J:
            if i > j:
                c[i, j] = c[j, i]

    (x_val, y_val, cost) = p_median_relaxed(I, J, c, d, p)

    for i in I:
        if y_val[i] <= 0.999:
            if y_val[i] >= 0.001:
                print(x_val)
                print(y_val)
                print(c)
                print(d)
                print(p)
                print(cost)
                print(' ')

                found_flag = 1
                break

    if found_flag == 1:
        break
```

I put this together quickly, so please let me know if I've made any errors or incorrect assumptions.

Comment: Yep, this is perfect. I should have tried your random approach. Thanks!